# How can I use docker build cache across GitLab CI jobs

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, docker-build

I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in my repo:

```yaml
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
docker-build-main:
  # Official docker image, develop tag
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker pull "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:develop-depsonly" || true
    - docker build --cache-from "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:develop-depsonly" --target build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:develop-depsonly" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:develop-depsonly"
    - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:develop" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:develop"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null
      when: on_success

docker-build-tag:
  # Official docker image, tagged release (also updates latest)
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker pull "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:develop-depsonly" || true
    - docker build --cache-from "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:develop-depsonly" -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:develop-depsonly"
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:develop-depsonly"
    - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    - docker push  "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: on_success
```

The way it's supposed to work is, it should build new images using old ones as cache. But I'm having two issues:

1. The caching doesn't work i.e. even though nothing is changed in the `build` target, it's still rebuilt from scratch.
2. The `docker-build-tag` recipe never runs. It should run whenever a new tag is created, but it's not running at all.

The `DockerFile` is as below:

```docker
FROM rust:1 as build
RUN cargo install cargo-build-deps

RUN cargo new --bin simply-shorten
WORKDIR /pkg

COPY ./actix/Cargo.toml .
COPY ./actix/Cargo.lock .

RUN cargo build-deps --release

COPY ./actix/src ./src
COPY ./actix/resources ./resources

RUN cargo build --release

FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc:latest

EXPOSE 2000
RUN apk add sqlite-libs

WORKDIR /opt

COPY --from=build /pkg/target/release/pkg /opt/pkg
COPY --from=build /pkg/resources /opt/resources

CMD ["./pkg"]
```

Comment: Please share your gitlab ci runner configuration as what you ask about depends on it. Which [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) are you using?

Comment: @hakre I'm using the Docker executor on shared runners.

Answer (score 2):

The `docker:dind` - and every other - service is running in isolation. This is why caching is not effective. While for you nothing changed in the build target, for Docker running within the `docker:dind` service, it is a clean state and it has never seen the build context so everything is new, shiny and fresh and so will be the build.

If you build always on the same instance and use the shell executor instead providing the docker command, you can share the docker build cache across all jobs. This would prevent all the isolation that is limiting your use and you could also have the registry already pre-authenticated and ready to use, too.

If that is not an option, you could try if moving the service to the toplevel (instead having it on each job) already makes a difference. But that could only be visible if you could answer yourself your second question about the not-behaving conditional on the second job. I'd suggest to remove it for testing first, and then rebuild it step-by-step to find out where it breaks your expectation.